# mysql statement remove repeated words in string

Tags: duplicates, mariadb

I would like to be able to use sql statement which allow me to remove record if there is repeated words in string column "title". 
There is several repeated word in title e.g "cervical cancer survival rate in the world cancer survivals"  I would like to search and remove this field because word "cancer" repeated. Note that there could be another word that I don't know repeated so it is not only cancer word that I am looking for.

```
table structure
table name hospital
ID Varchar(32) utf8_general_ci
Title Varchar(300) utf8_general_ci
Summary Varchar(300) utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: In versions of MySQL up to 5.7 this is not possible as REGEXP/RLIKE doesn't support back references.

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.6-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1  I guess mine one is the latest version of mysql should be okay.

Comment: @danone you have mariadb, not mysql. It is a fork of mysql, but they are no longer the same.

Comment: does that mean that I can't use regexp to find repeated words in mariadb ?

Comment: You want to `DELETE` the row?  Or what do you mean by "remove this field"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This applies to MariaDB, not MySQL.)

This will match a 'word':

```
[[:<:]]\w+[[:>:]]
```

Since you have MariaDB, this backreference is available:

```
\1
```

So, this should match a `title` with a duplicated word:

```
title REGEXP [[:<:]](\w+)[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]\1[[:>:]]
```

(Depending on the context, you may need to double up the backslash.)

Reference:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/
See also `REGEXP_REPLACE()`:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/